# How to write Python Django queries, and import them?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

**Data:**

```
{
  "Fruit": "Pomegranate",
  "District": "Nasik",
  "Taluka": "Nasik",
  "Revenue circle": "Nasik",
  "Sum Insured": 28000,
  "Area": 1200,
  "Farmer": 183
}

{
  "Fruit": "Pomegranate",
  "District": "Jalna",
  "Taluka": "Jalna",
  "Revenue circle": "Jalna",
  "Sum Insured": 28000,
  "Area": 120,
  "Farmer": 13
}

{
  "Fruit": "Guava",
  "District": "Pune",
  "Taluka": "Haveli",
  "Revenue circle": "Uralikanchan",
  "Sum Insured": 50000,
  "Area": 10,
  "Farmer": 100
}

{
  "Fruit": "Guava",
  "District": "Nasik",
  "Taluka": "Girnare",
  "Revenue circle": "Girnare",
  "Sum Insured": 50000,
  "Area": 75,
  "Farmer": 90
}

{
  "Fruit": "Banana",
  "District": "Nanded",
  "Taluka": "Nandurbar",
  "Revenue circle": "NandedBK",
  "Sum Insured": 5000,
  "Area": 2260,
  "Farmer": 342
}

{
  "Fruit": "Banana",
  "District": "Jalgaon",
  "Taluka": "Bhadgaon",
  "Revenue circle": "Bhadgaon",
  "Sum Insured": 5000,
  "Area": 220,
  "Farmer": 265
}
```

I want to write all types of combination queries, if someone wants information only for Fruit which is Guava then the output will be exact data for Guava only.

also if someone wants information only for  Fruit which is  Banana & Guava then the output will be exact data for Banana and Guava.

If  fruit is  equal to Banana

```
  output will be data for Banana
```

If fruit is  equal to Guava

```
  output will be data for Guava
```

If fruit is equal to Banana and Guava

```
  output will be data for Banana and Guava
```

Also, if someone wants information only for District which is Nasik then the output will be exact data for Nasik district only.
Query for "District"

If District is equal to Nasik

```
  output will be data for Nasik District
```

If District is equal to Nanded

```
 output will be data for Nanded District
```

likewise, there is query for "Revenue_circle, Farmer etc.

I know how to write this queries in mongoshell using find

`db.collections.find({"District":"Nasik"})` etc...

but I want to write the query in the python script.

Can you please help me to solve this problem? Any Hints?

**I tried and write in Models.py file**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User   
from django.db import models    
from django.db.models import Q

class Wbcis(models.Model):

    Fruit = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    District = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    Taluka = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    Revenue_circle = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    Sum_Insured = models.FloatField()

    Area = models.FloatField()

    Farmer = models.IntegerField()


    def __str__(self):

        return self.Fruit

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:

      verbose_name_plural = 'wbcis'


from models import Wbcis
Guava =Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava'))    
print Guava    
Banana= Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Banana'))    
print Banana        
Pomegranate= Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Pomegranate'))    
print Pomegranate
Guava_Banana=Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava')&Q(Fruit='Banana'))  
print Guava_Banana
Guava_Pomegranate=Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava')&Q(Fruit='Pomegranate'))
print Guava_Pomegranate
```

**I tried an I write in Views.py**

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from WBCIS.serializers import WbcisSerializer
from WBCIS.models import Wbcis 
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
from django.db.models import Q


class WbcisViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Wbcis.objects.all()

    serializer_class = WbcisSerializer

    filter_backends=[SearchFilter]

    search_fields=['Fruit','District','Sum_Insured','Area','Farmer','Taluka','Revenue_circle','id']   

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

        queryset_list =Wbcis.objects.all()

        queryset_list1 =Wbcis.objects.all()

        query =self.request.GET.get("Fruit")

        query1=self.request.GET.get("District")

        query2=self.request.GET.get("Taluka")


        if query and query1:

            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(Fruit__icontains=query)
            |Q(Distirct__icontains=query1)
            )

            return queryset_list

        elif query1:

            queryset_list1 = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(District__icontains=query1)
            )  

            return queryset_list1

        elif query:

            queryset_list1 = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(Fruit__icontains=query)
            )  

            return queryset_list1

        elif query and query2:

            queryset_list2 = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(Fruit__icontains=query)&
            Q(Taluka__icontains=query2)
            )  

            return queryset_list2

        return Wbcis.objects.all()
```

Is this correct way? or need some changes in models.py and views.py file?

Comment: Are you Using the django ORM for your data?

Comment: Yes,  I tried, Also I use django_mongoengine , but I want to writing a queires in python script which is ultimately going to call these queries from django. So,I am confuse

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a model in django so that you can use django's ORM to easily access the data. Here's some information on [Django models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/):

In the above, your model would be something like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    Fruit = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    District = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Taluka = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    RevenueCircle = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    SumInsured = models.IntegerField()
    Area = models.IntegerField()
    Farmer = models.IntegerField()
```

Then you'd be able to do a query like:

```
from models import Item
guava_items = Item.objects.filter(fruit='Guava')
print guava_items
# Out: [<guava item>, <guava item>, ...]
```

Comment: Okay, if  some one want information for banana_items than how to add another query ? need to use while loop?

Comment: @KiranPrajapati sure, you could have a `for fruit in ['Banana', 'Guava', 'Pomegranate']:`

Comment: I am confuse in while loop, can you give me idea for fruit using while loop?

Comment: So, my all queries write in  models.py file?

Comment: @KiranPrajapati, no, you layout your models (e.g. Item) in models.py, then you can perform a query anywhere really. Though, logically, you will perform the query in views.py

Comment: @KiranPrajapati you could run it in your models, but the point in django (an "MVC" framework) is to separate the model from the view. In your view (where you'd process the web request) you'd import your model and call it there. Or, you could just run it in a shell and not need to use any files.

Comment: @David542 Okay, I write in  queries models.py  like this , is that correct? from models import Wbcis

Guava =Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava'))
print Guava

Banana= Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Banana'))
print Banana
    
Pomegranate= Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Pomegranate'))
print Pomegranate

Guava_Banana=Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava')&Q(Fruit='Banana'))
print Guava_Banana               So, now for import this type in views.py for call there, right?

Comment: this is my views.py file              def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        queryset_list =Wbcis.objects.all()
        queryset_list1 =Wbcis.objects.all()
        query =self.request.GET.get("F")
        query1=self.request.GET.get("D")
        query2=self.request.GET.get("Sum_Insured")
        query2=self.request.GET.get("Area")
                
        if query and query1:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(Fruit__icontains=query)
            |Q(Distirct__icontains=query1)
            )
            return queryset_list

Comment: @KiranPrajapati it's too hard to read your code in the comment. Let's ask a new question?

Comment: @David542  I just editing and add this file in this question.